# How to pass int variable to another activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass an int value with an intent to another activity, but I always get 0. And it's not 0, I checked. I'm trying to pass value from int variable brojPoena. I tried this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Game.this, Popup_opis.class);
i.putExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", brojPoena);
```

and in my receiving activity:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent(); 
        if(mIntent !=null) {
           int brojPoena = mIntent.getIntExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", 0);
        }
tvBrojPoena.setText("You won " + brojPoenaPrimljeno + " points");
```

Also I tried this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Popup_opis.class);
i.putExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", brojPoena);
```

and in my recieving activity:

```
Bundle extrasPoeni = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extrasPoeni !=null) {
           brojPoenaPrimljeno = extras.getInt("brojPoena");
        }
```

My receiving activity:

```
public class Popup_opis extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView tvOpis,tvNaslov,tvBrojPoena;
    String poslatOpis, primljenOpis;
    int brojPoenaPrimljeno;
    Button OK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.popup_opis);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           primljenOpis = extras.getString("poslatOpis");
        }

        Bundle extrasPoeni = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extrasPoeni !=null) {
           brojPoenaPrimljeno = extras.getInt("brojPoena");
        }

        initVariables();

    }

    private void initVariables() {


        Typeface tv = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARIALN.TTF");
        OK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
        tvOpis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOpis);
        tvBrojPoena = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojPoena);
        tvBrojPoena.setTypeface(tv);
        tvNaslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNaslov);
        tvNaslov.setTypeface(tv);
        tvOpis.setTypeface(tv);
        tvOpis.setText(primljenOpis);
        tvBrojPoena.setText("Osvojili ste " + brojPoenaPrimljeno + " poena u ovoj igri.");



    OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, however as @codeMagic points out, you're probably not passing any value to the receiving activity.

Comment: I do, i've just tried to set that value to button as setText just above that Intent line and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is this variable `brojPoenaPrimljeno`? You have this

```
int brojPoena = mIntent.getIntExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", 0);
```

but are using a different variable name when you call `setText()`

You are trying to receive the value using the `value` instead of the `key`. When you create the `Intent`

```
i.putExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", brojPoena);  // brojPoenaPrimljeno is the key be trying to use to
```

Try

```
 brojPoenaPrimljeno = getIntent().getIntExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", 0);
```

Also, this is minor and not your problem but is inefficient and could cause problems. You are getting the `Intent in two different places. Here

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and here

```
Bundle extrasPoeni = getIntent().getExtras();
```

**Handling Intent from different `Activities`**

In case this helps, if I have an `Activity` receiving `Intents` from multiple places, I will use a `String extra` to tell the receiving `Activity` where it came from. For example:

Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, ReceivingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("source", "activityName");   // this will be used to know where the intent came from

```
//receiving activity
Intent recIntent = getIntent();
if (recIntent.getStringExtra("source") != null)
{
     String source = recIntent.getStringExtra("source");
    if (source.equals("activityName"))
    {
         // do stuff
    }
    if (source.equals("differentActivityName"))
    {
         // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darwind I almost did because this is on the borderline but its a little much for a comment and it is an answer if the OP is using the wrong variable name. Which, from the code given, that looks to be the case

Comment: That variable brojPoenaPrimljeno is my recieving variable. I'm sending brojPoena to brojPoenaPrimljeno in another activity.

Comment: You're right... however ? are frowned upon in answers ;-) But nudging the OP in the right direction I guess it's as good as an answer ;)

Comment: @marjanbaz In the first snippet it is not but in the second snippet it is. Which is suppose to be the variable in `setText()`? Did you put a breakpoint after the line where you check the variable to see the value?

Comment: @Darwind thanks and I mostly agree. I use a ? if I'm fairly confident that its the problem and hear it seemed to be. And I hate putting lines of code in a comment...so hard to read. But like I said, it is borderline and I will happily delete if it isn't the problem :)

Comment: @codeMagic - nono, it's fine - I removed by -1 ;-) And yes code doesn't belong in comments...

Comment: @Darwind I saw that and thank you! We can still be friends :P

Comment: @codeMagic I've edited my original post and pasted my whole recieving activity.

Comment: As you can see I use the same way to transfer some string between activities. And it work. With this int it does not.

Comment: @marjanbaz but your receiving activity is trying to find an `int` with the name `brojPoena` - the name of the `int` you're trying to pass is called `brojPoenaPrimljeno` - not `brojPoena`!

Comment: Are you talking about first or second option?

Comment: brojPoenaPrimljeno = getIntent().getIntExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", 0);   This worked. Thanks a lot. And about your second point...I'm getting intent in two different places cause I need one int (this one) and one string. I don't know a better to do it. If you, I'll be glad to learn one more thing. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't realize they were two different places. You should be fine then as long as you check for `null`

Comment: @marjanbaz I have added a small example of how I handle `Intents` from different `Activities`. There may be better ways but this seems to work for me. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, a good one. BUT, what if you have different type of variables sending to the same activity? :)

Comment: @marjanbaz You just check that it isn't `null` before initializing the variable. `if (getIntent().getStringExtra("key") != null) { String variableName = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");}