# Using the same button in other classes

Tags: android, eclipse, class, button

I am using eclipse and are programming my first app, but I have a beginner question, i want to use some of the methods from my button in the Main class, but i want to use them in my Start class, how do i set this up?

Is it by using:

```
Button1 = (Button) find View By Id(R.id.button1)
```

In every class i want to use it? Or is there a much simpler way?

I am not sure that this will give me the correct result, i am currently getting an error, and i don't know if this is the fault.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to create a `BaseActivity` and add the `Button` there along with its functionality. Then you can `extends BaseActivity` in the `Activities` which you want this `Button` to be used.

Doing this, you will need to use the `<include>` tag in the xml of your `Activities` that you want this `Button`. Now you can use this `Button` in other `Activities` and you can `override` the method that the `Button` uses if you need different functionality in certain `Activities`.

If doing it that way seems too complicated then you will need to put the `Button` in each xml and the associated functionality in the class that uses that xml. But you might give this a try...it can really make things easier and cut down on duplicate code.

[include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Another question, if i want to extend the Main class, but i have already extended Activity, how do i do this? I get an error if i write extends two times.

Comment: You're welcome. I use it to implement my own custom "Action Bar" and it works rather nicely.

Comment: You can't. You can only extend on class. That's why you create this `BaseActivity` which `extends Activity` and it will work fine because your other `Activities` then inherit the `Activity` objects, methods, and so forth

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your time.. ;) I have a question that is not about this subject, would you answer this or should i go somewhere else?

Comment: No problem. If its simply I can answer it here but if it requires code, errors, and is completely off topic then you should post a new question or else this post gets too confusing and doesn't help others

Comment: Okay, its pretty simple.. I have this app, with three windows. Main, Start and Stop. When i enter the start window i can push start in that window, and i want that action to change the start button in the main window. What is the best way to do that? By using a button set text and if else statement to change intent, or by changing visibility of buttons?

Comment: Use `intent.putExtra()` to send whatever you need to change the other `Button` to. Also, I posted an answer to your other question. Hope that helps. Knowing how to read logcat is key in development so I'm glad that you asked how to read logcat instead of expecting everyone to do it for you...kudos!

Comment: Okay, under the button i put this? Do i need to do something in the main class to receive the info? Thank you, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799637/how-to-pass-int-variable-to-another-activity/15799693#15799693) it should help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use button1 in your Start Class, then you also have to declare it in the Layout file of your Start Class.

You are getting an error most likely because that line of code will make the application search for button1 in your Start Class Layout file (which most likely isn't there).